# How can I reduce the size of PyCharm's content.dat.storageData cache?

Tags: python, pycharm

My `content.dat.storageData` file for PyCharm is huge (~8gb); is there any way for me to make it smaller?  Ideally I'd also like to be able to see what it contains.

I have already tried going to `File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart` as recommended in the JetBrains article [Cleaning out the system caches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cleaning-system-cache.html).

Is it safe to try to just delete the file?

[image]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cleaning-system-cache.html?

Comment: @IainShelvington Sorry, I forgot to mention that I had already tried that.  I'll update the post to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just deleting the file, and I haven't noticed any ill effects so far.

I believe the cache file had grown a few weeks ago when I placed a folder full of ~100,000 text files in one of my project files, which caused that folder to get indexed by PyCharm.  I later marked the folder-full-of-text-files to not be indexed, but the cache file remained large.

Answer (score 1):

in the options of pycharm there is a option "invalidate caches", thats the safe way